# Turning off Update Nag screens for Tor on OS X

Tags: update

my name is Festus.

Is there a way to turn off the nag screens (both popups and notifications) that ask me to update the TOR browser on Mac OS X?

(Generally speaking, I like to run the latest edition of whatever software I use. But in the case of TOR, there's a glitch in the update procedure that deletes all of my bookmarks whenever I update so I'd rather not receive each and every new edition).

I looked in Settings (Cmd-,) but see no options to turn off the nag screens. Is there some special service that I need to disable?

Thanks,

Festus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's really not advisable to skip an update, basically all the updates fix something that's security-relevant. That's why there is no way to remove the nagscreen without turning off the entire updater. To do that, type "about:config" into the url bar and then change the value of app.update.enabled to false.

Comment: Thank you. Festus finds your reply helpful. The config screen you referenced led him to the update-check *Interval* property, which he then reset to a more reasonable value. Festus does wish that TOR would fix the bookmark deletion glitch (see original post) so that each and every software update could be applied in a hassle-free way.

Comment: This is a naive view. When an update doesn't work properly, it is helpful to wait for the next version. When tor nags every time it's run, ick. @FestusMartingale has the right of it. The check interval is a fair work around.